# RecursiveList Python

Tags: python

So i'm learning about RecursiveLists and our prof has given us a **init** for the recursivelist class

```
class RecursiveList:
    # === Private Attributes ===
    # _first:
    #     The first item in the list.
    # _rest:
    #     A list containing the items that come after
    #     the first one.
    _first: Optional[Any]
    _rest: Optional[RecursiveList]

    # === Representation Invariants ===
    # _first is None if and only if _rest is None.
    #     This represents an empty list.

    def __init__(self, items: list) -> None:
        """Initialize a new list containing the given items.

        The first node in the list contains the first item in <items>.
        """
        if items == []:
            self._first = None
            self._rest = None
        else:
            self._first = items[0]
            self._rest = RecursiveList(items[1:])
```

now I want to mutate the list by inserting an item to the front of the list but I can't wrap my head around how to do so. I understand that `self._rest` stores the rest of the list recursively and also that I should move the value of `self._first` into `self._rest`, but how do I move an int and turn it so that the recursive function has the rest of them?

```
def insert_first(self, item: object) -> None:
    """Insert item at the front of this list.

    This should work even if this list is empty.
    """
```

Comment: You can use your method recursively on `self._rest`, using previous first element value as `item`.

Comment: Hopefully, your prof will make it clear that although the class is named `RecursiveList`, it is actually a `Linked List` (as @L3viathan noted). Lists can be `Linked Lists` and methods can be `recursive`,  as any computer science document from the past several decades will support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make a new `RecursiveList` (btw: This is usually called a [Linked List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)) that you copy your current value to, make its `rest` point to your current `rest`, overwrite your own element with the element to be inserted, and set your `rest` to the new list.

Something like:

```
def insert_first(self, item: object) -> None:
    """Insert item at the front of this list.

    This should work even if this list is empty.
    """
    if self._first is None:
        # handle case where list is "empty"
        self._first = item
    else:
        new = RecursiveList()
        new._first = self._first
        new._rest = self._rest
        self._first = item
        self._rest = new
```

---

```
Before:

1:"e" -→ 2:"l" -→ 3:"l" -→ 4:"o"

After:

1:"h"    2:"l" -→ 3:"l" -→ 4:"o"
   |        ↑
   └→5:"e" -┘
```

Note that this process is a what is called constant-time operation, because it doesn't matter how large the list is: this process always takes roughly the same amount of time. This (constant-time insertion at the beginning of the list) is somewhat unique to Linked Lists, and does not apply to Python's normal lists, which are based on arrays.